# Upload file to AWS S3 using a PUT request volley (in Android)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-volley, multipart

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon s3 using a PUT request from my android application. I have got a link from server with private key exposed in the same.

When trying to upload the file from POSTMAN its working when uploaded using binary option and content type application/octet-stream or application/x-www-form-urlencoded (Tried with both) in header but if uploading same image using form data its not working.

In my android application i have tried JsonObject request using volley in which i am getting.

**Json Org exception**

**Please find my request below**

```
     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                url, new JSONObject(parameters),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            Log.e("Response", response + "");

                            listener.onResult(response + "", responseCode);
                            if (showDialog == true) {
                                try {
                                    mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                                }

                                try {
                                    materialDialog.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                                } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (listener != null) {
                            try {
                                if(error.networkResponse!=null && error.networkResponse.data!=null) {
                                    String responseBody = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                                    if (!responseBody.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                                        listener.onResult(data + "", responseCode);
                                        //listener.onResult(error.toString(), WebAPIConstants.VOLLEY_ERROR);
                                        Log.e("ERROR", error.toString() + "");
                                    } else {

                                        listener.onResult("", responseCode);
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                    listener.onResult("", responseCode);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException errorr) {
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }
                        }
                        if (showDialog == true) {
                            try {
                                mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }

                            try {
                                materialDialog.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                            } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }

                        }
                        try {

                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    }
                                });

                            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                if (CheckInternetConnection.haveNetworkConnection(mContext)) {

                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {


                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                        }
                                    });


                                }

                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            Crashlytics.logException(e);
                        }

            }
```

(Have sent image in bytecode), On using String request the image is being uploaded but with **size 1kB but dosent open on server** (Have sent image in bytecode).

**String request**

```
     StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                if (listener != null) {

                            Log.e("Response", response + "");


                            if (showDialog == true) {
                                try {
                                    mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                                }

                                try {
                                    materialDialog.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                                } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                                }

                            }
                        }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (listener != null) {
                            try {
                                if(error.networkResponse!=null && error.networkResponse.data!=null) {
                                    String responseBody = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                                    if (!responseBody.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                                        listener.onResult(data + "", responseCode);
                                        //listener.onResult(error.toString(), WebAPIConstants.VOLLEY_ERROR);
                                        Log.e("ERROR", error.toString() + "");
                                    } else {

                                        listener.onResult("", responseCode);
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                    listener.onResult("", responseCode);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException errorr) {
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }
                        }
                        if (showDialog == true) {
                            try {
                                mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }

                            try {
                                materialDialog.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                            } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }

                        }
                        try {

                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    }
                                });

                            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                if (CheckInternetConnection.haveNetworkConnection(mContext)) {

                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {


                                    AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_title), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                        }
                                    });


                                }

                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            Crashlytics.logException(e);
                        }
                }

        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                if (listener!=null) {

                    listener.onResult(mStatusCode + "", responseCode);
                }

                 mStatusCode = response.statusCode;

                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);


            }



            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return parameters;
            }



            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                return headers;
            }



        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(120000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        try {

            stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
            queue.getCache().clear();
            queue.add(stringRequest);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
```

Have also tried Multipart request but getting errors like **auth error** etc.

**Multi part request where docUrl is same url as in postman**

Dependency added for below request:

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

**MultipartRequestAWS class**

package spice.mudra.csp_cred;

```
    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;

    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

    public class MultipartRequestAWS extends Request<String> {
    private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
        private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

        private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
        private final File mFilePart;
        private final String mStringPart;



        public MultipartRequestAWS(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,File file, String stringPart) {
            super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

            mListener = listener;
            mFilePart = file;
            mStringPart = stringPart;
            buildMultipartEntity();
        }

        private void buildMultipartEntity()
        {
            entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
            try
            {
                entity.addPart(STRING_PART_NAME, new StringBody(mStringPart));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType()
        {
            return "application/octet-stream";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try
            {
                entity.writeTo(bos);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
            }
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
        {
            return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(String response)
        {
            mListener.onResponse(response);
        }
    }
```

****Multipart request****

```
MultipartRequestAWS request = new MultipartRequestAWS(docUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("Responce", "" + response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Responce", "" + error);
                    }
                }, outputFile, imageArray.toString()
                );


                request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(300000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                //adding request to request queue
    //            if(!Constants.IS_PRODUCTION) {
                Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    //            }else{
    //                Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity(), new OKHttpStack(new URL(request.getUrl()).getHost())).add(request);
    //
    //                // Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity(), new HurlStack(null, newSslSocketFactory())).add(request);
    //            }
```

**Other Multipart request tried**

```
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        private final String mimeType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;

//multipartBody is byte code of image to be uploaded

        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(url, null, mimeType, multipartBody, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                        try {
                            mOverlayDialogAsync.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Crashlytics.logException(e);
                        }

                        try {
                            materialDialogAsync.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Crashlytics.logException(e);
                        }







                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    try {
                        mOverlayDialogAsync.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }

                    try {
                        materialDialogAsync.dismiss(); // To hide the progress bar
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }


                    try {
                        // getting json string form the response obtained from server
                        String jsonString = new String(error.toString());

                        Log.e("response multipart", jsonString);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }


                    try {


                        //Network errors handling

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(CustomDialogNetworkRequest.this, getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                }
                            });

                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            if (spice.mudra.utils.CheckInternetConnection.haveNetworkConnection(AddYourProffDetails.this)) {

                                AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(AddYourProffDetails.this, getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title), getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_string), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {


                                AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(AddYourProffDetails.this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_title), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message), new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    }
                                });


                            }

                        } else {

                            AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(AddYourProffDetails.this, "", "Something went wrong. Please try again.", new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                }
                            });


                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }


                }
            });

            //setting timeout to multipart request
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(300000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


            //adding request to request queue


                Log.i("++++++++++", "Request body: " + new String(request.getBody()));
                Volley.newRequestQueue(CustomDialogNetworkRequest.this).add(request);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
        }
```

Please help with the same.

Please find POSTMAN screenshot for reference. This also has URL type that i am using.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For uploading image file add the following functions to your StringRequest object. Here outputFileUri is the Uri of the file which you want to upload. s3Url is the s3 bucket url where you want to place the image file.

```
            StringRequest putRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, s3Url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                }
            }){

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "image/jpeg";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(outputFileUri);
                byte[] b = new byte[8192];
                for (int readNum; (readNum = inputStream.read(b)) != -1; ) {
                    bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                return bos.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(putRequest);
```